# Loading C# WCF config through DLL called by Delphi

Tags: c#, wcf, delphi, dll, config

I have a WCF client in a DLL which I call in Pascal/Delphi.

When I run my program as a console application after a build - in the same path as my config file - there are no errors.
However, when I build it as a dll instead of an exe and then call it through Pascal/Delphi code, I receive the following error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ClientService.IClientService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

This is the exact same error I get when I try to run it as a console application without the config file!

Any help / tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: We don't know how you are doing your interop

Comment: I encountered the same problem as you, I ended up making the wcf binding config at runtime and pass some config parameters via the DLL